# Installing python Github package error: package directory 'src' does not exist

Tags: installation, pip, package

I am new at installing external Github packages into python.

I successfully cloned a package by running the command

```
git clone https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi.git
```

However, when I ran

```
python setup.py install
```

I received the error:

```
No sequencer available for 'win32' platform.
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:341: UserWarning: 
Normalizing 'v0.2.3' to '0.2.3'
normalized_version,
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating midi.egg-info
writing midi.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to midi.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to midi.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'midi.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
**error: package directory 'src' does not exist**
```

Is this a directory problem? And is there another approach to install this package (possible via pip)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readme on git hub has: "I am extremely interested in supporting OS-X and Win32 sequencers as well, but I need platform expert who can help me. Are you that person? Please contact me if you would like to help."
So it is simply not supported on Win32.